# How to fix refused to display url in a frame because it set x frame options to deny in webkitgtk python

Tags: python, gtk, x-frame-options, webkitgtk

Im building a simple web browser with Python, Gtk, and WebKitGtk. When trying to load youtube, i receive this error message:

console message: about:blank @0: Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26feature%3Dpassive%26hl%3Den%26next%3D%252Fsignin_passive&hl=en&passive=true&service=youtube&uilel=3' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

my code (from a tutorial on webkitgtk):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.win.set_title('window')
        self.win.set_default_size(1200, 800)

        self.btn_grid = Gtk.Grid()

        self.btn_grid.set_column_spacing(10)
        self.reload_button = Gtk.Button('Reload')
        self.reload_button.connect('clicked', self.reload_window)
        self.btn_grid.attach(self.reload_button, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.url_entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.url_entry.set_hexpand(True)
        self.url_entry.connect('activate', self.display_url)
        self.btn_grid.attach(self.url_entry, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.go_btn = Gtk.Button('Go')
        self.go_btn.connect('clicked', self.display_url)
        self.btn_grid.attach(self.go_btn, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.main_box = Gtk.VBox()
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.btn_grid, False, False, 0)
        self.win.add(self.main_box)

        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
        self.webview.connect('title-changed', self.title_update)
        self.webview.load_uri("https://google.com")


        self.scroll_area = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scroll_area.add(self.webview)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.scroll_area, True, True, 0)
        self.win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

    def title_update(self, webview, frame, title):
        self.win.set_title(f'window - {title}')

    def display_url(self, event):
        url = self.url_entry.get_text()
        if url == '':
            pass
        else:
            if "://" not in url:
                url = f'https://{url}'
            self.webview.load_uri(url)
            self.webview.grab_focus()

    def reload_window(self):
        self.webview.reload()


    def w_open(self):
        self.win.show_all()

main_window = Main()
main_window.w_open()
Gtk.main()
```

How could i fix this problem? YouTube loads fine on other web browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ethically set X-Frame-Options on the `iframe`, `object` or similar other browser tags or browser `windows` etc. That is a response header set by the domain from which you are requesting the resource (google.com in your example). They have set the header in this case, which means that they have disallowed loading of the resource.  For more information see [The X-Frame-Options response header on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

If the requesting webapge belongs to you, then you can set `X-Frame-Options` headers in the response, but looks like that is not the case.
I don't know what you are trying to do, I presume you are logging in to Youtube in your app, you can not directly do it as it requires google authentication, you would need to take a look at [google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) before you integrate.